# The "Web Setup Wizzard" on Magento 2.2.5-dev redirects to the admin dashboard

Tags: magento2, extensions, web-setup-wizard, magento2.2-dev

I'm using Magento version 2.2.5-dev as a testing space for some things. Basically I have a company that wants to just have a magento instance to experiment with for some time before deciding on an eCommerce platform to move forward with.

The install went just fine. Everything is working as intended with no noticeable hiccups.

However when you attempt to navigate to the Web Setup Wizard I'm just redirected to the admin dashboard. I would like to use the Component Manager to install some modules/extensions they'd like to test from the marketplace.

There are two user account in the system. Both administrators, and they both get the same results. No errors are thrown, it just returns to the admin dashboard.

I've tried upgrading the system, rerunning composer, and flushing all the caches. Nothing seems to help.

Could anybody shine some light on why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest you run a stable version of Magento. Especially if you're going to showcase it to a client. You're also not going to find many running 2.2.5-dev at this stage, so your replies are going to come a lot slower.

I'm running M 2.2.4 on a couple sites and it does not have any issues with the Web Setup Wizard. I'm sure this is not the answer you were looking for but something to consider. Good luck!

Comment: @RudyC. , Stable actually means nothing on the Magento life cycle. I am using 2.2.4 and no version in the past 2 years was really "stable".